# Templated structure inheriting from another Templated Structure

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I would like my templated derived class der to inherit from foo.
This is just a test code and I wanted to see if I am taking the correct approach here
The der class itself is templated and what I want to  do is to pass the template types of its base class foo in the initialization list der class. I am using the following code

```
template<typename t , typename u>
struct foo
{
  void foo_method(t inp , u out)
  {
        std::cout << inp + out << "\n";
  }
};


template <typename m>
struct der : public foo<t,u> //Error t was not declared in the correct scope
{
  der():foo<t,u>(int,int)//I want to specify the types for the base class in initialization list
  {

  }
};


int main()
{
   der<std::string> d;

}
```

Now when I try to run the above code I get

```
Error t was not declared in the correct scope
```

Any suggestions on how I could fix this ?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what `foo<>` you want to inherit from if you don't provide template arguments?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. `foo` does not have a two argument constructor, so what are you trying to pass to it? And what are `t` and `u` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
template <typename m>
struct der : public foo<int,int>
{
  der():foo<int,int>()
  {

  }
};
```

Comment: Of course, the compiler-generated version already calls the base class default-ctor.

Comment: then we dont need foo<int,int>() . I wanted to know if its possible to specify them in the initialization list. I am curious about that

Comment: @MistyD: If you mean *only* specify them there, then no, but I'm not quite sure what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also how would I call a method of the base class say foo_method ? foo<int,int>::foo_method(); does not seem to work ?

Comment: @MistyD: It depends on the context. If you are in a method of class `dir`, then because of inheritance, you can simply say `foo_method()`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? I can't really tell what you're asking for in your question.

Reproduced at http://ideone.com/dBCkQb

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename t, typename u>
struct foo{
    foo(t a, u b) : x(a),y(b)
    {

    }
    t x;
    u y;
};

template <typename m, typename t, typename u>
struct der : public foo<t,u>{
    der(m a, t b, u c) :foo<t,u>(b,c), z(a)
    {

    }
    m z;
};


int main() {
    der<int,double,float> myder(1,1.03,2.05);
    cout << myder.x << endl << myder.y << endl << myder.z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```